# Windows 7. Remote printer access

Tags: windows-7, printer, remote-access

I have 2 computers on local network (`comp01`, `comp02`). On `comp02` I have installed printer. Now on `comp01` I am adding remote printer (the one I have installed on `comp02`) onto the computer. Printer is working fine.

But after I restart `comp01` the printer icon is getting disabled

[image]

, thus I can't send documents to the printer.

I found out that If I connect to `comp02` (Win+R -> IP of `comp02`) then the printer icon is getting enabled again and I can use the printer.

**How do I configure printer settings on `comp01` so that after I restart `comp01` I don't have to connect to `comp02`?**

When I add remote printer or connect to remote PC a login form is popping out. I am typing in relevant user name and password. At the bottom part of the form there is a checkbox with `remember` label. I am assuming that system will remember the credentials but however neither checking nor unchecking the checkbox didn't help.

Both computers are running under Windows 7.

I have administrator account on both computers. The users are member of `users` group on each computer. I have let them share printers.